# Update progress bar with media player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-progressbar

I tried to use the `MediaPlayer` and display the current position in the `ProgressBar`. The media player itself works, but the `ProgressBar` displays nothing. Below is the code:

```
final Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(audioFile);
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), fileUri);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}).start();


progress = findViewById(R.id.audioProgressBar);
audioDuration = mp.getDuration();
progress.setMax(100);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus <= audioDuration) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        float progressFloat = ((float) mp.getCurrentPosition() / mp.getDuration()) * 100;
                        progress.setProgress((int) progressFloat);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: The audioDuration is the length of the audio file

Answer (score 1):

Since you are initializing mediaPlayer in different thread, the value you might be getting `getDuation` might be empty or incorrect as well since you do not know for sure whether mediaPlayer is initialized or not.

Try using the following method as it will eliminate the method of setting Max progress again and again(since different song lengths hence setMax will change).

Set progress max to 100 instead of audioDuration.

```
progress.setMax(100);
```

Then in your handler calculate progress as follows

```
//current value in the text view
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Calculate progress
        float progress = ((float) mp.getCurrentPosition() / mp.getDuration()) * 100;

        progress.setProgress((int) progress);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it like you said (I edited my question above), sadly it skips the handler and nothing happens with the progressBar, do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Might be due to `progressStatus`. What is progressStatus? Can you explain? Can you remove that part and see if it works?

Comment: when i remove the progressStatus, it still skips the run handler, the plan with the progress status was that the progressBar stops when 100 is reached

Comment: If you use the method above it will stop at 100 by default as the max value is 100

Comment: But still nothing happens with the progressBar, that it stops at 100 is clear